# Android Increment counter value on button onClick

Tags: android, auto-increment

I want to save a list in my database as List1, List2,-----, List(n+1). It is saving my list, but everytime I save a list it starts from List1. I want to save my list by picking the last saved List and increment it by 1. How to perform this?

code:

```
btn_save_list.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ++counter;
                showSavelistDialog(counter);

        }
    });
private void showSavelistDialog(int counter) {
if (!list.isEmpty()) {

        String draftName=  "Draft"+counter;
        SaleDraftDatabase saleDraftDatabase = new SaleDraftDatabase(
                mActivity);
        saleDraftDatabase.open();

        boolean nameAvailable = saleDraftDatabase
                .checkDraftNameAvailable(userId,draftName);
        if (nameAvailable) {
            boolean saveCheck = saleDraftDatabase.createEntry(list,
                    userId,draftName);
            saleDraftDatabase.close();
            if (saveCheck) {
                SalesReturnDatabase saleDatabase = new SalesReturnDatabase(
                        mActivity);
                saleDatabase.open();
                saleDatabase.deleteAllEntriesOfSingleUser(userId);
                saleDatabase.close();
                list.clear();
                barcodeList.clear();
                Intent i = new Intent(mActivity,
                        Activity_Sales_Return.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(
                        Activity_Sales_Return.this,
                        draftName
                                + " sale saved as draft.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(Activity_Sales_Return.this,
                        "Some error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(mActivity,
                    "Name already in use. Choose another name.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

use static `counter` value.

```
private static int counter = 0;
```

so that its increment is same on all objects.

or alternatively, save counter value in `SharedPreference`.